# Posted to multiple Stack* sites, put on hold here for being off-topic

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, cross-posting

I was desperate for an answer and asked the same question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198010/unable-to-configure-font-in-xterm) and on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809617/unable-to-configure-font-in-xterm) and it's been put on-hold here as being off-topic.

However, given the nature of the question, I feel it's more relevant here. StackOverflow also says that it's too old to migrate. Will deleting it from there be sufficient to remove the on-hold status?

Comment: The SO version seems to have an accepted answer; is it not solved?

Comment: I found the answer (missing freetype lib support) and for the sake of completeness, I'd like to post it here under "Your Answer" as suggested by @Anthon. However, I can't do that till it's removed from on-hold.

Comment: Question can be put on hold **only** for being asked by the same person on multiple Stack Exchange sites, but, for some reason, when that happens, it it just says that it was closed for being off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the right thing to do is since the SO version is too old to migrate and can't be deleted with an accepted answer. I just reopened our version so you can post the answer (and edit it out of the question), and I guess we'll have both around, which is unfortunate for the people who find the SO version

Comment: I could delete the SO answer but I don't want to do that since Thomas provided a detailed response that helps answer a lot of the question.